# Gallai's lemma from Tutte's theorem?

Tags: graph-theory

I have seen a proof of [Tutte's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tutte_theorem) from Gallai's lemma. Lovasz also said in his [*Matching Theory*](http://books.google.com/books?id=yW3WSVq8ygcC) that Gallai's lemma can be easily proven from Tutte's theorem. But I cannot figure out how.

[image: Matching Theory, by Lovasz and Plummer, p. 89]

> **3.1.13. THEOREM.** (*Gallai's Lemma*). *If graph $G$ is connected and $\nu(G-u)=\nu(G)$ for each $u \in V(G)$, then $G$ is factor-critical.*
>   We remark that an easy proof would follow from Tutte's Theorem, but here we choose a more direct proof based on Corollary 3.1.7.

Thanks!

Comment: Which Gallai's lemma? Which Tutte's theorem? Both these gentlemen proved a nontrivial number of results.

Comment: @Igor, and @darij: See my edit please.


Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gallai's Lemma certainly follows from the somewhat more general [Tutte–Berge formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tutte%E2%80%93Berge_formula), which easily follows from Tutte's theorem.

Let $G$ be a connected graph such that $\nu(G-u)=\nu(G)$ for all $u \in V(G)$ and let $U$ be a set which gives equality in the Tutte-Berge formula.  Suppose $U$ is non-empty and $x \in U$.  Evidently, $(G-x)-(U-x)$ has the same set of odd components as $G-U$.  By the Tutte-Berge formula, it follows that $\nu (G-x) < \nu (G)$, which is a contradiction.  Therefore, $U=\emptyset$.  By the Tutte-Berge formula, we have that either $G$ has a perfect matching (if $G$ has an even number of vertices) or a matching covering all vertices except one (if $G$ has an odd number of vertices).  Since $\nu(G-u)=\nu(G)$ for all $u \in V(G)$, the first possibility is impossible, and so the second possibility holds.  Thus, $G-u$ has a perfect matching for all $u \in V(G)$, as required.

Comment: Thanks! If I am correct, (G−x)−(U−x)=G−U if and only if x is in U?

Comment: You're welcome and yes you are correct.  

Answer (score -1):

What would be the definition of $\nu(G)$ in this book?

Comment: This should be a comment, unless it is going to be turned into an answer.

Comment: @David Roberts: New users are not allowed to comment until they acquire a small amount of reputation points @Lima: If you answer (or ask) a few questions (likely just one), you'll be able to make comments

Comment: I'll edit this with an answer soon.
@Tom I was wondering exactly that. Thank you for the info.